# Adding anchor tag to javascript URL

Tags: php, javascript, url

I have a PHP system and basically I use a popup lay to do some processing, ie upload an image. No problems here and then on completing the insert and upload I go to a page which will call the underlying page and refresh it:

```
$callpage="jobsheet_build.php?id=".$_GET['id'];
echo("<script language=\"javascript\">");
echo("top.location.href = \" ").$callpage.("\";");
echo("</script>");
```

OK this works fine, but in the ideal world I would like to put a reference to #images in the $callpage so I end up with

```
$callpage="jobsheet_build.php?id=".$_GET['id']."#images";
```

but the javascript just hangs no matter what I do.

Any ideas would be very greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your problem is with the javascript - please show the generated javascript

Comment: What's the actual output of that script? I'd assume you want `echo("top.location.href = \" ".$callpage."\";");` as opposed to what you've got there (with the extra brackets).

Comment: the whole thing is within a php block so the callpage ends up as "jobsheet_build.php?id=XXXX". The echos are in there to output the javascript when the PHP runs. This means the penultimate line outputs as top.location.href="jobsheet_build.php?id=XXX";

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If you want to output `#images` in the string, just add it in, surely. If the Javascript is hanging, then we need to see the Javascript.

Comment: it is all the script I have mentioned. That is the entire script on the php template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jim Have you tried to set the anchor tag like this `echo("top.location.href = \" ").$callpage.("#images\";");` instead of set the anchor tag inside the variable ?